# Is studying/reading astrology in purpose of nullifying it haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Studying sihr is Haram unless your purpose is nullifying it. But does that goes for astrology too? How about believing that astrology star signs have its own name in order to avoid using them for anything? How about showing people zodiac signs just to tell them not to believe in them? Please answer all my questions. I need answers.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to find names in Arabic. If you do not find anything then it is just names. These names itself means nothing. You should find about these names in many astrological books written in Arabic or by Arabic writers.